# Clojurescript self compilation for node

Tags: node.js, clojure, clojurescript

I've been following along the clojurescript self compilation news, including most recently http://www.yogthos.net/posts/2015-11-12-ClojureScript-Eval.html

Would a similar approach work with nodejs as a target? Although the bootstrapped REPL is very cool, I'm interested in compiling (or otherwise making executable) cljs files with node. I'm hoping this would make writing and running clojure(script) scripts on old / embedded hardware a less painful experience in terms of JVM startup time and memory consumption. Is this a reasonable hope? How would I go about producing such an executable from cljs source? Thank you for your input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out https://github.com/kanaka/cljs-bootstrap

This can easily be installed via `npm install -g cljs-repl`. After doing that you can run a `*.cljs` file via `cljs foo.cljs`.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose it should work with node.js w/o problems but do you need self-hosting at all? How about compiling it locally and shipping compiled js (with optimization set to none)?

If it is an option, this may be helpful: https://github.com/bhauman/lein-figwheel/wiki/Node.js-development-with-figwheel

Comment: True. To clarify, I was hoping to do the development on said old/embedded hardware, for educational and hobby purposes, more adhoc scripting than something meriting deployment.

Comment: Oh, I see. Then I'd just go ahead and try, then post a blog article/create a library. Good luck!

Comment: So I guess my question should be, how do I create a .js file for node (presumably compiled from cljs) which, given a cljs source file, can either run it directly, or produce js for node?

Comment: I haven't done it myself but I imagine the same way you do self-hosting in the browser, i.e. using `eval-str`. Have you encountered any problems when  trying that?

Comment: As a side note, IMVHO if you plan to use the self-hosting thing as a means to an end, I'd reconsider developing using JVM compiler simply because the toolset is mature (leiningen, figwheel).